# Dynamic slide show in SharePoint 2013

Tags: dynamic, sharepoint-2013, slideshow

How to build a slideshow(dynamic) in SharePoint 2013. I have already tried OOTB but all of them are static.I have also tried some java script but even scripting cannot give create dynamic slide show.
By dynamic I mean that if I edit the list/library (from SharePoint itself) that change must be reflected back on the slide show. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is sevrals solution.
You could use the SharePoint Search and the display template for generate you slideShow.
 You can find a tuto here : [Image Slider with SharePoint 2013 Search Results Web Part](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/image-slider-with-sharepoint-2013-search-results)
Or you can dev it with pure JS script. 
[A SIMPLE JQUERY CONTENT SLIDER](http://summit7systems.com/a-simple-jquery-content-slider-for-sharepoint-200720102013-and-o365/)

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't forget to validate the answer (if it is correct) for other people